# Automatizar login em um pop-up no chrome (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automatização

estou aprendendo automatização com python utilizando jupyter notebook e selenium

Consegui executar todas as etapas para extração e manipulação dos dados. Entretando, estou enfrentando problemas para fazer login no site a partir de um pop-up do chrome.

Primeiramente, fiz a importação das bibliotecas utilizadas no meu código.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#bibliotecas para automatizar consulta 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#biblioteca para delay de tempo
from time import sleep

#biblioteca para mover e renomear arquivos
import os

#biblioteca para análise de dados
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import datetime
```

Em sequencia, configuro o navegador e o acesso ao site

```
navegador = webdriver.Chrome()
navegador.get("https://[endereço]/Consulta.aspx")
```

Na terceira fase, meu objetivo era preencher esse campo automaticamente:

[image: Pop-up que se abre assim que acesso o site]

Já tentei buscar todas as identificações possiveis para automatizar essa parte, bem como acessei as documentações e outras publicações na internet e falhei miseravelmente.

As demais etapas do meu projeto funcionaram adequadamente, com preenchimento automático, salvamento e edição de arquivos. Todos rodando bem. Meu real problema é qual código eu faço para fazer login neste tipo de pop-up.

Essa é a minha primeira publicação no stackoverflow. Aceito feedbacks sobre como melhorar minha elaboração de perguntas.Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá Felipe tenta colocar o usuário e senha no link por ex:
De https://www.example.com | Para https://admin:admin@www.example.com
Nesse caso o user e a senha é admin.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou!